# ASP.NET Web API: How do you set up OWIN Cors to work on a specific API Controller not globally

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm using an OWIN based ASP.NET Web API 2 application and trying to set up CORS. The app uses some custom processing that has its own internal CORS processing, but we have a few standard API controllers that require CORS configuration.

The problem is I've been unable to use **per controller** CORS configuration. I need to enable the built-in CORS only for specific controllers. However I can't get `[EnableCors]` to work.

I've:

- Added the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`
- Added [EnableCors] to my controller
- Made sure I have a different `Origin` in my request

Code for the controller:

```
EnableCors(origins: "*",headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
public class RawUploadController : ApiController
```

Code compiles fine. But when I hit the endpoint I get no CORS headers.

If I add the OWIN CORS package and I change the code to use the OWIN CORS implementation `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)` everything works as expected, but I no longer have control over what requests use CORS - every request now fires CORS headers. The problem with this is that this affects our custom processing logic (which does its own CORS processing) and the CORS headers on those components double up which is not correct.

So...

The question is how do I properly set up CORS for WebAPI hosted under OWIN to work on a per controller basis?

**Update:**

The problem turned out to be that I didn't enable CORS in startup.

I still needed the following:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();

        ...
    }
```

According to the docs it looks like `config.EnableCors()` is meant be used with **global config** as you can pass parameters for global CORS config, but the parameterless version  is **required when using the attribute**.

Operator error on my part, but I'm leaving this up here in case anybody else runs into this silly mistake.

Comment: Have you tried with [EnableCors(origins: "*" , headers: "*" , methods: "*")]? Note: Add the * sign in every parameter, the comment field dont show the sign..

Comment: Yes that's what I'm using. Updated the question to clarify.